# A guide to convert_imageset.cpp

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I am relatively new to machine learning/python/ubuntu.

I have a set of images in .jpg format where half contain a feature I want caffe to learn and half don't. I'm having trouble in finding a way to convert them to the required lmdb format.

I have the necessary text input files.

My question is can anyone provide a step by step guide on how to use `convert_imageset.cpp` in the ubuntu terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 64, accepted):

### A quick guide to Caffe's `convert_imageset`

#### Build

First thing you must do is build caffe and caffe's tools (`convert_imageset` is one of these tools).
After installing caffe and `make`ing it make sure you ran `make tools` as well.
Verify that a binary file `convert_imageset` is created in `$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools`.

#### Prepare your data

*Images:* put all images in a folder (I'll call it here `/path/to/jpegs/`).
*Labels:* create a text file (e.g., `/path/to/labels/train.txt`) with a line per input image  . For example:

> img_0000.jpeg 1
>   img_0001.jpeg 0
>   img_0002.jpeg 0

In this example the first image is labeled `1` while the other two are labeled `0`.

#### Convert the dataset

Run the binary in shell

```
~$ GLOG_logtostderr=1 $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/convert_imageset \
    --resize_height=200 --resize_width=200 --shuffle  \
    /path/to/jpegs/ \
    /path/to/labels/train.txt \
    /path/to/lmdb/train_lmdb
```

Command line explained:

- `GLOG_logtostderr` flag is set to 1 *before* calling `convert_imageset` indicates the logging mechanism to redirect log messages to stderr.
- `--resize_height` and `--resize_width` resize **all** input images to same size `200x200`.
- `--shuffle` randomly change the order of images and does not preserve the order in the `/path/to/labels/train.txt` file.
- Following are the path to the images folder, the labels text file and the output name. Note that the output name should not exist prior to calling `convert_imageset` otherwise you'll get a scary error message.

Other flags that might be useful:

- `--backend` - allows you to choose between an `lmdb` dataset or `levelDB`.
- `--gray`    - convert all images to gray scale.
- `--encoded` and `--encoded_type`  - keep image data in encoded (jpg/png) compressed form in the database.
- `--help`    - shows some help, see all relevant flags under *Flags from tools/convert_imageset.cpp*

You can check out [`$CAFFE_ROOT/examples/imagenet/convert_imagenet.sh`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/imagenet/create_imagenet.sh)
for an example how to use `convert_imageset`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great guide.  I took a slightly different route and edited the _create_imagenet_ script. However upon running it I got the follow error; i.e. **" a total of 0 images"**  Creating train lmdb...
I0715 16:54:06.121748  4120 convert_imageset.cpp:79] Shuffling data
I0715 16:54:06.122463  4120 convert_imageset.cpp:82] A total of 0 images.
I0715 16:54:06.123065  4120 db.cpp:34] Opened lmdb /home/pwhc/caffe/GPRLearn/lmdb/GPR_train_lmdb  Any thoughts?

Comment: @pwhc it seems like no image files were found. check the path to images and the image names in the labels gile

Comment: when reference in the train and test text files i included the file trype; as in **$DATA/train.txt** when it should have simply been **$DATA/train**. Appreciate the guidance

Comment: how can you have all your images in a single folder and yet still have a train/test text file? where does the train/test split take place then?

Comment: @pwhc you need to construct **different** lmdb/leveldb for train/test. Therefore, you need **two** different files `/path/to/labels/train.txt` and `/path/to/labels/test.txt` the image names in those files should be different, but they can point to images in the same or in different folders - it's up t o you to organize them.

Comment: so the lmdb train/test databases are defined by the text files?

Comment: @Shai best Tutorial for caffe! Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain why first image is 1 and the other two are 0? you mean there is only 1 positive image and the other two are negative images? what if I have positives in one folder and negatives in another folder?

Comment: @SaeidYazdani it's all the way you list the images in the list

Comment: @Shai: Regarding what you mentioned that "Therefore, you need two different files /path/to/labels/train.txt and /path/to/labels/test.txt the image names in those files should be different, but they can point to images in the same or in different folders - it's up t o you to organize them.", is it OK if I use the same filename but it's put in different directories i.e. in train and val directories, just like I did in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559763/directory-structure-and-labeling-in-caffe)?

Comment: @alfa_80 if the paths (directories) are different then the files are **not** the same. It's up to you to organize the images. Just make sure you do not test on images that were in the training set -this is cheating

Comment: @Shai: Thanks for the answer. Yes, they both are totally different images although having the same name, so as to avoid over-fitting (remembering instead of having generalization capability).

Comment: @Shai I can't create the binary. When I run `make tools` I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'tools'.`. What is happening?

Comment: @yellow01 this usually means your tools are already compiled and up to date