# Creating an image LMDB for Caffe2

Tags: python, machine-learning, caffe, lmdb, caffe2

In the original Caffe framework, there was an executable under `caffe/build/tools` called `convert_imageset`, which took a directory of JPEG images and a text file with labels for each image, and output an LMDB that could be fed to a Caffe model to train, test, etc.

What is the best way to convert raw JPEG images and labels to an LMDB that Caffe2 can ingest using the `AddInput()` function from this [MNIST tutorial](https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/python/tutorials/MNIST.ipynb) on the Caffe2 website?

According to my research, you cannot simply create an LMDB file using this tool and feed a Caffe2 model.

The tutorial script just downloads two LMDBs (`mnist-train-nchw-lmdb` and `mnist-test-nchw-lmdb`) and passes them to `AddInput()`, but gives no insight as to how the LMDBs were created.

Comment: You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37149186/1714410) to see how to create lmdb in python.

Answer (score 0):

There is a binary called `make_image_db.cc` which does precisely what you are describing. It is located in `caffe2/build/bin/make_image_db`:

```
// This script converts an image dataset to a database.
//
// caffe2::FLAGS_input_folder is the root folder that holds all the images
//
// caffe2::FLAGS_list_file is the path to a file containing a list of files
// and their labels, as follows:
//
//   subfolder1/file1.JPEG 7
//   subfolder1/file2.JPEG 7
//   subfolder2/file1.JPEG 8
//   ...
```

As described in https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/issues/1755 you can use the binary in the following way (also with fewer parameters):

```
caffe2/build/bin/make_image_db -color -db lmdb -input_folder ./some_input_folder
-list_file ./labels_file -num_threads 10 -output_db_name ./some_output_folder -raw -scale 256 -shuffle
```

A full Caffe2 example on how to create and read a lmdb database (for random images) can be found in the official github repository and can be used as a skeleton to adapt to your own images https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/python/examples/lmdb_create_example.py. Since I have not used this method yet, I will simply copy the example. In order to create the database, one can use:

```
import argparse
import numpy as np

import lmdb
from caffe2.proto import caffe2_pb2
from caffe2.python import workspace, model_helper

def create_db(output_file):
    print(">>> Write database...")
    LMDB_MAP_SIZE = 1 << 40   # MODIFY
    env = lmdb.open(output_file, map_size=LMDB_MAP_SIZE)

    checksum = 0
    with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
        for j in range(0, 128):
            # MODIFY: add your own data reader / creator
            label = j % 10
            width = 64
            height = 32

            img_data = np.random.rand(3, width, height)
            # ...

            # Create TensorProtos
            tensor_protos = caffe2_pb2.TensorProtos()
            img_tensor = tensor_protos.protos.add()
            img_tensor.dims.extend(img_data.shape)
            img_tensor.data_type = 1

            flatten_img = img_data.reshape(np.prod(img_data.shape))
            img_tensor.float_data.extend(flatten_img)

            label_tensor = tensor_protos.protos.add()
            label_tensor.data_type = 2
            label_tensor.int32_data.append(label)
            txn.put(
                '{}'.format(j).encode('ascii'),
                tensor_protos.SerializeToString()
            )

            checksum += np.sum(img_data) * label
            if (j % 16 == 0):
                print("Inserted {} rows".format(j))

    print("Checksum/write: {}".format(int(checksum)))
    return checksum
```

The database can then by loaded by:

```
def read_db_with_caffe2(db_file, expected_checksum):
    print(">>> Read database...")
    model = model_helper.ModelHelper(name="lmdbtest")
    batch_size = 32
    data, label = model.TensorProtosDBInput(
        [], ["data", "label"], batch_size=batch_size,
        db=db_file, db_type="lmdb")

    checksum = 0

    workspace.RunNetOnce(model.param_init_net)
    workspace.CreateNet(model.net)

    for _ in range(0, 4):
        workspace.RunNet(model.net.Proto().name)

        img_datas = workspace.FetchBlob("data")
        labels = workspace.FetchBlob("label")
        for j in range(batch_size):
            checksum += np.sum(img_datas[j, :]) * labels[j]

    print("Checksum/read: {}".format(int(checksum)))
    assert np.abs(expected_checksum - checksum < 0.1), \
        "Read/write checksums dont match"
```

Last but not least, there is also a tutorial on how to create a minidb database: https://github.com/caffe2/caffe2/blob/master/caffe2/python/tutorials/create_your_own_dataset.ipynb. For this, one could use the following function:

```
def write_db(db_type, db_name, features, labels):
    db = core.C.create_db(db_type, db_name, core.C.Mode.write)
    transaction = db.new_transaction()
    for i in range(features.shape[0]):
        feature_and_label = caffe2_pb2.TensorProtos()
        feature_and_label.protos.extend([
            utils.NumpyArrayToCaffe2Tensor(features[i]),
            utils.NumpyArrayToCaffe2Tensor(labels[i])])
        transaction.put(
            'train_%03d'.format(i),
            feature_and_label.SerializeToString())
    # Close the transaction, and then close the db.
    del transaction
    del db
```

Features would be a tensor containing your images as numpy arrays. Labels are the corresponding true labels for the features. You would then simply call the function as

```
write_db("minidb", "train_images.minidb", train_features, train_labels)
```

Finally, you would load the images from the database by

```
net_proto = core.Net("example_reader")
dbreader = net_proto.CreateDB([], "dbreader", db="train_images.minidb", db_type="minidb")
net_proto.TensorProtosDBInput([dbreader], ["X", "Y"], batch_size=16)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of just posting a link, you should post the relevant parts in your answer. This creates a more complete answer, and would ensure your answer is still relevant if that link ever breaks

Comment: @AfroThundr You are right, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

for create database in lmbd:
create the train data folder 
create train.txt file conataining filename label
create validation data folder
create val.txt file contatining filename and label

**edit this file**

```
gedit examples/imagenet/create_imagenet.sh
```

```
EXAMPLE= path to where *.lmbd folder wil be stored
DATA= path where val.txt and train.txt is present
TOOLS=build/tools

TRAIN_DATA_ROOT=test/make_caffe_data/train/ # path to trainfiles
VAL_DATA_ROOT=test/make_caffe_data/val/ # path to test_files
```

Set `RESIZE=true` to resize the images to 256x256. Leave as `false` if images have
 already been resized using another tool.
`RESIZE=true`

**`./examples/imagenet/create_imagenet.sh`**