# How to Create CaffeDB training data for siamese networks out of image directory

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, training-data

I need some help to create a CaffeDB for siamese CNN out of a plain directory with images and label-text-file. Best would be a python-way to do it.
The problem is not to walk through the directory and making pairs of images. My problem is more of making a CaffeDB out of those pairs.
So far I only used [`convert_imageset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410) to create a CaffeDB out of an image directory.
Thanks for help!

Comment: what loss layer are you going to use?

Comment: I don't know yet. For my use case I have some images (100k) for each class (4 + garbage class) and I want the net to distinguish between classes better. With "normal" linear CNN there were to much mistakes of the net and I thought of trying a siamese CNN to make the net learning the differences better.
If you have some suggestions on good loss layer, please tell me.

Comment: contrastive loss layers seems to be suitable for this use case.

Comment: thx for that, so problem with caffeDB remains...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you simply make two datasets using good old `convert_imagest`?

```
layer {
  name: "data_a"
  top: "data_a"
  top: "label_a"
  type: "Data"
  data_param { source: "/path/to/first/data_lmdb" }
  ...
}
layer {
  name: "data_b"
  top: "data_b"
  top: "label_b"
  type: "Data"
  data_param { source: "/path/to/second/data_lmdb" }
  ...
}
```

As for the loss, since every example has a class label you need to convert `label_a` and `label_b` into a `same_not_same_label`. I suggest you do this "on-the-fly" using a python layer. In the `prototxt` add the call to python layer:

```
layer {
  name: "a_b_to_same_not_same_label"
  type: "Python"
  bottom: "label_a"
  bottom: "label_b"
  top: "same_not_same_label"
  python_param { 
    # the module name -- usually the filename -- that needs to be in $PYTHONPATH
    module: "siamese"
    # the layer name -- the class name in the module
    layer: "SiameseLabels"
  }
  propagate_down: false
}
```

Create `siamese.py` (make sure it is in your `$PYTHONPATH`). In `siamese.py` you should have the layer class:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0,os.environ['CAFFE_ROOT'] + '/python')
import caffe
class SiameseLabels(caffe.Layer):
  def setup(self, bottom, top):
    if len(bottom) != 2:
       raise Exception('must have exactly two inputs')
    if len(top) != 1:
       raise Exception('must have exactly one output')
  def reshape(self,bottom,top):
    top[0].reshape( *bottom[0].shape )
  def forward(self,bottom,top):
    top[0].data[...] = (bottom[0].data == bottom[1].data).astype('f4')
  def backward(self,top,propagate_down,bottom):
      # no back prop
      pass
```

Make sure you shuffle the examples in the two sets in a different manner, so you get non-trivial pairs. Moreover, if you construct the first and second data sets with *different* number of examples, then you will see different pairs at each epoch ;)

---

Make sure you construct the network to share the weights of the duplicated layers, see [this tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html) for more information.

Comment: I found no siamese.py file, neither in caffe/python nor in python2.7 install dir. I'm working on Ubuntu 15.04 and got the caffe-master branch in 10/2015.  
There is only the mnist siamese example and I already designed the net like in the tutorial with shared parameter, only the beginning with the data input is not clear to me. I don't use a python layer so far. I just define the net and run caffe with train command for a given solver.prototxt.  
Like: caffe train -solver solver.prototxt -gpu all.  
My data layer refers to directory with *.mdb and the mean binaryproto file

Comment: @Feuerteufel you need to **create** a `siamese.py` file and make sure it is in your `$PYTHONPATH`. this file should contain the code in the question (along with the proper `import`s that are required to `import caffe`). If you enabled a python layer in your [Makefile](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile.config.example#L82) than caffe will run the python code for you as part of its `caffe train`.

Comment: Ok, python layer was not enabled so I'm rebuilding it right now. The proper lines for imports for the siamese.py are "import sys", "sys.path.insert( 0, 'path/to/caffe/python' )" and "import caffe" or something more? In the loss layer the same_not_same_label is then used as third input?

Comment: @Feuerteufel same_not_same_label is used as the label for the contrastive loss.

Comment: If I have N labels. How can I enforce, that the feature vector of size N right before the contrastive loss layer represents some kind of probability for each class? Or comes that automatically with the siamese net design?

Comment: @Feuerteufel that is a big question. I cannot answer this in a comment. consider posting this as a new question

Comment: ok, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946937/how-to-enforce-feature-vector-representing-label-probability-with-caffe-siamese

Comment: @Shai I followed your instruction but I get this error:  `Check failed: layer_param.propagate_down_size() == layer_param.bottom_size() (1 vs. 2) propagate_down param must be specified either 0 or bottom_size times`, which doesn't make sense because I set `back_propagate: false`. Where else could've gone wrong?

Comment: @MoneyBall this is beyond the scope of a comment. please consider asking a new question

Comment: @Shai do you by any chance know if there is a C++ code for such layer that I can plug and play?

Comment: @MoneyBall hdf5data can be quite versatile