# Create dataset for LeNet?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, computer-vision, caffe, vision

I'm working on a project for which I'd like to create a dataset of drawn faces (similar in concept to the CUFS dataset). Hand-drawing the faces aside, how would I go from "I have uploaded these image files to my computer and have ensured that they all have identical dimensions" to having a ready-to-use dataset? (I'd like to train/test LeNet with this dataset.) I've never created my own dataset before so am pretty unsure as to how to start.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [guide to use convert\_imageset.cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427094/guide-to-use-convert-imageset-cpp)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the images into levelDB or LMDB. You can follow the exsample of `convert_mnist_data.cpp`.