# Pipeline for py-faster-rcnn on custom datasets with VGG16 on caffe

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I would like to use an existing VGG16 model trained on imagenet and fine-tune it with a custom dataset for some other classes required by me.

Where can I find the caffemodel, train_val.prototxt and solver.prototxt for the same ?

To fine-tune it with the custom dataset, is the procedure same as

[Fine Tuning of GoogLeNet Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841158/fine-tuning-of-googlenet-model?lq=1)

[A guide to convert_imageset.cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427094/guide-to-use-convert-imageset-cpp/31431716#31431716)

?

However, I want to use the newly-trained weights of the VGG16 model to train a faster RCNN (py-faster-rcnn) https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn on a custom dataset. 
For training faster RCNN on a custom dataset, I was planning on following the steps given here http://sgsai.blogspot.com/2016/02/training-faster-r-cnn-on-custom-dataset.html

Will the caffemodel generated from the VGG16 fine-tuning done earlier work here or some tweaks need to be done ?