# How to load the image with caffe?

Tags: c++, caffe

I'm writing code for machine learning program using Caffe-windows.
I want to load the image file. but, I don't know that convert image to leveldb. 
Can not load the image? I mean, I want the image load. not leveldb data.

I'm using caffe-windows and visual studio 2013.

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to load a single image to test the net, or do you want to load many images to train it?

Comment: have you looked into the python interface for caffe [`caffe.io.load_image`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py#L279)?

Comment: Hi Shai.
I'm using cpp. 
And, I want to load many images to train.

Comment: So why don't you use [`convert_imageset`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427094/guide-to-use-convert-imageset-cpp) to prepare a dataset for training?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting images to db(leveldb/lmdb) files can speed up your training because it can reduce the time needed by the network to read  images from your disk.

If you still not want to, you can use layer with type "**ImageData**" instead of "Data" in your prototxt and set its' param by

`image_data_param {
    source: "path/to/your/images/list.txt"
}`

Every line in list.txt provides the path of your image and its' label.