# Bug with the create_lmdb.py file

Tags: python-2.7, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I'm using code from [this](https://github.com/adilmoujahid/deeplearning-cats-dogs-tutorial/blob/master/code/create_lmdb.py) github, following [this](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/) tutorial. 
There are **few changes that I did**, because I'm training the CNN on my data. But, probably there is a problem with the changes I performed in `'create_lmdb.py'` file. the difference between the two databases are:

first: I'm training my network with *32x32* images.
second: my database includes only *grayscale* images.
but - I train my network for binary classification too.

After the modifications, this is my file:

```
import os
import glob
import random
import numpy as np

import cv2

import caffe
from caffe.proto import caffe_pb2
import lmdb

#Size of images
IMAGE_WIDTH = 32
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 32

def transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT):

    #Histogram Equalization
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    #img[:, :, 1] = cv2.equalizeHist(img[:, :, 1]) not a RGB
    #img[:, :, 2] = cv2.equalizeHist(img[:, :, 2])

    #Image Resizing
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) # make sure all the images are at the same size

    return img


def make_datum(img, label):
    #image is numpy.ndarray format. BGR instead of RGB
    return caffe_pb2.Datum(
        channels=1, #not an RGB image
        width=IMAGE_WIDTH,
        height=IMAGE_HEIGHT,
        label=label,
        data=img.tostring())

train_lmdb = '/home/roishik/Desktop/Thesis/Code/cafe_cnn/first/input/train_lmdb'
validation_lmdb = '/home/roishik/Desktop/Thesis/Code/cafe_cnn/first/input/validation_lmdb'

os.system('rm -rf  ' + train_lmdb)
os.system('rm -rf  ' + validation_lmdb)


train_data = [img for img in glob.glob("../input/train/*png")]
test_data = [img for img in glob.glob("../input/test1/*png")]

#Shuffle train_data
random.shuffle(train_data)

print 'Creating train_lmdb'

in_db = lmdb.open(train_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
    for in_idx, img_path in enumerate(train_data):
        if in_idx %  6 == 0:
            continue
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT)
        if 'cat' in img_path:
            label = 0
        else:
            label = 1
        datum = make_datum(img, label)
        in_txn.put('{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx), datum.SerializeToString())
        print '{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx) + ':' + img_path
in_db.close()


print '\nCreating validation_lmdb'

in_db = lmdb.open(validation_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
    for in_idx, img_path in enumerate(train_data):
        if in_idx % 6 != 0:
            continue
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT)

        prec=int(img_path[(img_path.index('prec_')+5):(img_path.index('prec_')+8)])

        if prec>50:
            label = 1
        else:
            label = 0

        datum = make_datum(img, label)
        in_txn.put('{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx), datum.SerializeToString())
        print '{:0>5d}'.format(in_idx) + ':' + img_path
in_db.close()

print '\nFinished processing all images'
```

But I think that according to the training results: the .mdb output file is corrupted (maybe empty or something - even its weights 47MB).

Can anyone see something wrong with this file? or, alternatively, give me a link to a good tutorial about building lmdb files?

Really appreciate your help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it!
After looking deeper into the code I noticed that I updated only the labels of the validation dataset (and skipped the training data) :P
it can be seeing in this piece of code:

```
 img = transform_img(img, img_width=IMAGE_WIDTH, img_height=IMAGE_HEIGHT)
        if 'cat' in img_path:
            label = 0
        else:
            label = 1
```

that belongs to the original tutorial.

**Conclusion:** if you can't access your lmdb file, mabey it's because the function that creates it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an `'lmdb'` image dataset for training a classification net, don't sweat! Caffe already has a tool just for that purpose!
You are looking for `$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/convert_imageset` tool and you can find quite a detailed (if I may say so;) tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I started with building a new file and then found my mistake :P