# can I resize images in create_images.sh to a bigger value?

Tags: caffe

I have images of size 2754*3778 and I want to use caffe for training. In the `create image.sh` file which is for converting the `.jpg` images to `.lmdb` format, the default resize value is 227*227. Can I change it to other values? if yes how much I can change? when I change it to my images value it does not work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [guide to use convert\_imageset.cpp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427094/guide-to-use-convert-imageset-cpp)

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not work"? be specific. add error message/log if you have.

Comment: @Shai it does not work I mean that I get `.lmdb` file created but when I view it all the values are zero!!!!