# Caffe's way of doing data shuffling

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, shuffle

Is shuffling done by setting the flag *--shuffle* as below as found in *create_imagenet.sh* ? :

```
GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
   --resize_height=$RESIZE_HEIGHT \
   --resize_width=$RESIZE_WIDTH \
   --shuffle \
```

I mean I don't need to shuffle it manually afterwards, if the flag does it already. What about the label, is it shuffled automatically in the generated *lmdb* file?

Comment: if the data is shuffled and the labels are not, how can you use the resulting dataset for training? it becomes meaningless...

Comment: Yes,  I was wondering too. Fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`convert_imageset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410) tool creates a **copy** of your training/validation data in a binary database file (either in [lmdb](/questions/tagged/lmdb) or [leveldb](/questions/tagged/leveldb) format). The data encoded in the dataset includes pairs of example and its corresponding label.
Therefore, when `shuffle`-ing the dataset the labels are shuffled with the data to maintain the correspondence between data and its ground-truth label.
There is no need to shuffle the data again during training.