# Optical flow input for Caffe

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, opticalflow

I wonder if Caffe can take optical flow image as input, instead of RGB. I am aware that there is such library like FlowNet that learns optical flow, but that is not what I am aiming at.

Please provide me a pointer if any.

Comment: What do you mean by an "optical flow image" ? How many channels are there ? What is the value range in each pixel ? As far as I know, caffe can take an image with any number of channels (3 in case of RGB, 1 in case of grayscale etc)

Comment: caffe can use whatever input you feed it. It's up to you to make sure it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Jayant & Shai.

Comment: @Shai: Can you please make it as an answer out of the comment you've made so that I can mark it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caffe is a very flexible framework. It can process almost any shape of input data you might provide it with.
A very common way to input images to caffe is via `lmdb`/`leveldb` datasets created using [`convert_imageset` tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410).
For more complex input shapes one can use binary `hdf5` files to be read using `"HDF5Data"` layer.

As for optical flow, you can input it as an image via `lmdb` or as a two-channel tensor via `hdf5`. Caffe can handle either way, *it's up to you to make sure the net knows how to make sense of the input data*.

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean by two-channel tensor in this context, by the way?

Comment: @alfa_80 in many cases optical flow is given by an x-direction displacement and y-direction displacement per-location. Thus you have a 3D array (aka "tensor") with two channels (x-displacement, y-displacement) -by-height-by-width.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for the explanation Shai!