# db_lmdb.hpp:15] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (2 vs. 0) No such file or directory

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have been trying to run the squeeznet model for quite some time now,after resolving multiple errors,i am stuck with this one-

when i run the command

```
./build/tools/caffe train -solve SqueezeNet/SqueezeNet_v1.0/solver.prototxt
```

i get

```
I0723 16:26:58.532799 11108 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer data
F0723 16:26:58.629655 11108 db_lmdb.hpp:15] Check failed: mdb_status 
== 0 (2 vs. 0) No such file or directory
***     Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fb24de835cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fb24de85433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fb24de8315b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fb24de85e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fb24e23efd8  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()
    @     0x7fb24e2b541f  caffe::DataLayer<>::DataLayer()
    @     0x7fb24e2b55b2  caffe::Creator_DataLayer<>()
    @     0x7fb24e290a59  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7fb24e29343e  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7fb24e22a315  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7fb24e22b6f5  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7fb24e22ba0f  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @     0x7fb24e21c851  caffe::Creator_SGDSolver<>()
    @           0x40a958  train()
    @           0x4072f8  main
    @     0x7fb24c50c830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x407bc9  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like caffe cannot find the LMDB database storing your training/validation data.

Make sure that the LMDB pointed by the path in `source: ...` parameter in your `"Data"` layer exists and that you have read permissions for this dataset.

Comment: this is what it says in the train.val file-- data_param {
    source: "examples/imagenet/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 32 #*iter_size
    backend: LMDB
  }   but the ilsvrc12_train_lmdb file is not in the examples folder!!-where do i find it??

Comment: @Ryan I guess you'll have to [create it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410).

Comment: hey shai! i have one question -i see that there is an imagnet folder in caffe,does it cantain the imagent data? or do we still have to download the images from the imagenet dataset?

Comment: @Ryan if you haven't downloaded it, it's not there.

Comment: sorry to bother you shai, one of the instructions in the squeezenet installtion process says:Helpful hints:

Getting the SqueezeNet model: git clone <this repo>. In this repository, we include Caffe-compatible files for the model architecture, the solver configuration, and the pretrained model (4.8MB uncompressed).

but if i have to download the imagenet datat for it to train,whats the point?or am i missing something obvious?

Comment: @Ryan the authors offer you to download the parameters of the net **after** they trained it on the data (4.8MB). If you want to train it yourself you'll have to download the data yourself (GBs of images.) It's up to you.

Comment: thanks shai-i have to type this because it wont accept just  thanks shai.