# Crop size Error in caffe Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Im trying to train a caffe Model.I get this error

```
I0806 09:41:02.010442  2992 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 360, lr = 9.76e-  05
F0806 09:41:20.544955  2998 
data_transformer.cpp:168] Check failed: height<=datum_height (224 vs. 199)
***  Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f82b051edaa  (unknown)
    @     0x7f82b051ece4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f82b051e6e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f82b0521687  (unknown)
    @     0x7f82b0b8e9e0  caffe::DataTransformer<>::Transform()
    @     0x7f82b0c09a2f  caffe::DataLayer<>::load_batch()
    @     0x7f82b0c9aa5
caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::InternalThreadEntry()
    @     0x7f82b0b6ea30  caffe::InternalThread::entry()
    @     0x7f82b0b6f376  boost::detail::thread_data<>::run()
    @     0x7f82a6afea4a  (unknown)
    @     0x7f82a1147184  start_thread
    @     0x7f82aee51ffd  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was getting a similar error but `Check failed: height<=datum_height (227 vs. 224)` .I then changed 227 to 224 ,but now i get this.Any suggestions?

EDIT:My code for LMDB-

```
EXAMPLE=/home/hyperworks/colorfile/   # Path where the output LMDB is stored
DATA=/home/hyperworks/colorfile/      # Path where the data.txt file is present 
TOOLS=/home/hyperworks/caffe/build/tools/   # Caffe dependency to access the convert_imageset utility 
DATA_ROOT=/home/hyperworks/colorfile/train/ # Path prefix for each entry in data.txt
# +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

# ----------------------------

RESIZE=true
if $RESIZE; then
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=227
  RESIZE_WIDTH=227
else
  RESIZE_HEIGHT=0
  RESIZE_WIDTH=0
fi

# Checks for DATA_ROOT Path
if [ ! -d "$DATA_ROOT" ]; then
  echo "Error: DATA_ROOT is not a path to a directory: $DATA_ROOT"
  echo "Set the DATA_ROOT variable to the path where the data 
   instances are stored."
  exit 1
fi

# ------------------------------
# Creating LMDB
 echo "Creating data lmdb..."
 GLOG_logtostderr=1 $TOOLS/convert_imageset \
    $DATA_ROOT \
    $DATA/train.txt \
    $EXAMPLE/train_lmdb

# ------------------------------
echo "Done."
```

This is the code i used to create the LMDB files- 
This is the code i used to create the LMDB files-

Comment: I think that value should be under the 199, like "190".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like one (or more?) images in your input dataset has `height` = 199. Caffe cannot crop image with height 199 to size 224.

Error message explained:

> ```
> data_transformer.cpp:168] Check failed: height<=datum_height (224 vs. 199)
> ```

Looking at the [`'data_transformer.cpp'` line 168](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp#L168):

```
CHECK_LE(height, datum_height);
```

the data transformer checks that the crop height (`height`) is less than or equal (LE) to the input `datum_height`.
As you can see from the error message, this check failed, meaning input height is larger than the crop height. The condition `height=224 <= datum_height=199` does not hold and an error is raised.

Comment: i used a resize operation while making the lmdb files to resize it to 227*227,But im still getting the same error.what should i change or edit?

Comment: @Ryan apparently resizing did not work as expected. Can you show the code you used for creating the lmdb? Are  you sure you are using the right LMDB?

Comment: It seems like you copied the code from [`create_imagenet.sh`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/imagenet/create_imagenet.sh), but you ignore `--resize_height` and `--resize_width` arguments. Please read **carefully** the [guide to `create_imageset.cpp`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31427094/1714410) and follow the instructions there.

Comment: will go through this