# Working with training a network of own dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have found a tutorial about how to [train a neural net](https://chunml.github.io/ChunML.github.io/project/Training-Your-Own-Data-On-Caffe/). How should I train a `caffe module` with my own dataset.

There is an axample `Cats vs Dogs` and it's clear for me, how I need to do with that data which consists of two types (`Dogs` and `Cats`). I have tried to follow his steps, and I got a result `caffe module`.

Then I would like to increase the type set, I mean, I have trained only on `2` types, now I want `19` types (yes, `19` - different objects) to train.

And the problem I have found is how should I increase the main selection
in a caffe module?

Here is the part of the code where I found a problem:

```
dog_images = [image for image in os.listdir(DATA_DIR) if 'dog' in image]
cat_images = [image for image in os.listdir(DATA_DIR) if 'cat' in image]

dog_train = dog_images[:int(len(dog_images)*0.7)]
dog_test = dog_images[int(len(dog_images)*0.7):]

cat_train = cat_images[:int(len(cat_images)*0.7)]
cat_test = cat_images[int(len(cat_images)*0.7):]
```

I don't think that if I have `19` types, it means, I need `19` times to write the code like that (`upper`).

Also, I have my images not in different folders, I have one and there are about `4,000` images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to repeat that code 19 times. The only purpose of this code is to create `'train.txt'` and `'test.txt'` files that lists your image files and the label of each image.
I don't know how you organize the images on your disk (you say you have a single folder with 4K images) but you should be able to tell what label/class (`0..18`) each image belongs to. Once you have these lists in the file `'train.txt'` and `'test.txt'` you can proceed to cread train and validation datasets using [`convert_imageset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427094/a-guide-to-convert-imageset-cpp) tool.

Comment: Yes, thanks for replying. But as for my dataset, can you inform me , if I have my images in order, like: 0000.jpg , 0001.jpg .... 4000.jpg. ? How should I show my labels of my objects (0..18)

Comment: @X21 what is the label of `0001.jpg`? and `0002.jpg`? how do **you** know the labels?

Comment: That’s why I ask you. Because I don’t understand enough. Do I need to store pictures with labels , for example: scarf. jpg, dress.jpg and etc? So I need 19 folders with different objects. Am I right?

Comment: @X21 You only need a **list** that connects each image to its label. You should have two lists: one with **train** images and the other with **test** images. Each list has the format of `0001.jpg 3\n0002.jpg 15\n` etc. (assuming label of `0001.jpg` is 3 and `0002.jpg`'s 15...)

Comment: Thank you , I will try to do this.